# Unable to Hide Android Overflow Menu When Certain Fragments Are Displayed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, overflow-menu

### What I Have Achieved

I am working on an Android application that uses a navigation drawer, attached to my MainActivity, to display certain layouts upon the user's selection of a navigation item. I also created a menu resource file for an overflow menu that should appear in the appBar.

### What I Am Unable to Achieve

However, the overflow menu I created is displayed in the appBar regardless of the user's selected navigation drawer item. **I need to, if possible, hide this overflow menu from the appBar when layouts calendar/settings are displayed.** (Code found below)

### What I Have Attempted to Do

I have tried playing with the `setHasOptionsMenu()` method and setting it to false in my calendar/settings Java files.

### Application Code

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.lukeb.calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Html;
import android.transition.Visibility;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    // Declare needed objects as global variables for access throughout the program

    RelativeLayout lay1;
    RelativeLayout lay2;
    RelativeLayout lay3;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    // Default method called automatically when activity is created

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);         // Set the content of this activity to the activity_main XML file
        navigate();                                     // Once finished with this, call the navigate function found below
    }

    // Method created to prep navigation drawer

    public void navigate(){                                 // Method called in onCreate method

        // If device is running Lollipop or above, run the following...
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar3);            // Set variable "toolbar" to item named "toolbar3" in XML file
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);                               // Designate the item set to "toolbar" as the activity's actionBar
            actionBar = getSupportActionBar();                          // Set variable "actionBar" to whatever the activity's actionBar is. This is necessary for checking it later.
            lay1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.one);             // Initialize variables "lay1", "lay2", and "lay3" - that were originally declared above - to their respective XML items.
            lay2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.two);             //    < __________________________|           |
            lay3 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.three);           //    < ______________________________________|


            drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.dLayout);   // Initialize variable "drawerLayout" to XML item "dLayout".
            if (actionBar != null) {                                    // Check if the activity's actionBar has been set (not equal to null)
                actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);              // Enables the actionBar's back button
                ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {       // Create a new AppDrawer toggle. Refer to android documentation for more info on parameters. Also defines its own constructor after the class object.
                    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {  // Method called when drawer is closed
                        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();      // Declare that the options menu has changed, so should be recreated. It will be recreated when needed.

                    }

                    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView){    // Method called when drawer is opened
                        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();             // Once again, declare that the options menu has changed, so should be recreated. It will be recreated when needed.

                    }
                };
                mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);      // Enable drawer indicator on the "mDrawerToggle" which, in turn, enables the animated glyph on the activity's actionBar
                drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);      // Set the appDrawer's actionListener to our newly created "mDrawerToggle" object
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();                          // Sync the appDrawer's indicator with the current state of the DrawerLayout
                setListener();                                      // Call the setListener method below

            }
        }
    }

    // Sets the item listener
    public void setListener(){
        NavigationView nView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);    // Declare a variable named "nView" and initialize it to the "nav_view" XML item.
        nView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);                          // Set the listener called for a selected navDrawer item to one found below
    }


    // A method that is called when a navDrawer item is selected
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){                                               // Check which item was selected by returning its ID
            case R.id.action_feed:                                              // If the item selected's ID is "R.id.action_feed"
                actionBar.setTitle("Your Feed");                                // Set actionBar title to correct page title
                lay3.setVisibility(View.GONE);                                  // Hide layout3 from the "stack of layouts"
                lay2.setVisibility(View.GONE);                                  // Hide layout2 from the "stack of layouts"
                lay1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                               // Show only the selected item on screen

                break;                                                          // Leave or "break" from the loop

            case R.id.action_calendar:                                          // If the item selected's ID is "R.id.action_calendar"
                actionBar.setTitle("Calendar");                                 // Set actionBar title to correct page title
                lay1.setVisibility(View.GONE);                                  // Hide layout1 from the "stack of layouts"
                lay3.setVisibility(View.GONE);                                  // Hide layout3 from the "stack of layouts"
                lay2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                               // Show only the selected item on screen
                break;                                                          // Leave or "break" from the loop

            case R.id.action_settings:                                          // If the item selected's ID is "R.id.action_settings"
                actionBar.setTitle("Settings");                                 // Set actionBar title to correct page title
                lay1.setVisibility(View.GONE);                                  // Hide layout1 from the "stack of layouts"
                lay2.setVisibility(View.GONE);                                  // Hide layout3 from the "stack of layouts"
                lay3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                               // Show only the selected item on screen
                break;                                                          // Leave or "break" from the loop

        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);                          // Regardless of selection, close drawer when loaded
        return true;                                                            // Return true if navDrawer item was indeed selected
    }

    public boolean newEvent(MenuItem item){
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewEvent.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**FragOne**

```
package com.example.lukeb.calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragOne extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // Creates a new view for the fragment. Then, it sets the XML layout file as the contents of the view. Finally, a copy of this new view is returned.

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag_one, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
        //inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.overflow_one, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

}
```

**FragTwo**

```
package com.example.lukeb.calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragTwo extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // Creates a new view for the fragment. Then, it sets the XML layout file as the contents of the view. Finally, a copy of this new view is returned.

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag_two, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but I've recently been trying to hide the overflow menu and thought it may be beneficial for anyone viewing this question to see my solution.

---

You're right to be looking at the `setHasOptionsMenu()`, however, I think you're a bit confused about what this does. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)), this method just tells the activity that it would like to populate the options menu. I've posted my solution below in the hope that it helps you, feel free to ask any questions if you don't understand.

---

My First step was to edit my menu resource file to add all of the items into a group. Mine now looks something like this:

```
<group
    android:id="@+id/main_menu_group">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</group>
```

I then override the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` method like so:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Log.d("Method Calls" , "onPrepareMenuOptions");
    menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.main_menu_group, false);
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

This code removes the visibility of all the items in the group created earlier, because of this, there's no need for the options menu, so android doesn't show it.

This code doesn't yet do anything as the options menu has already been created by the activity, using `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in the fragments `onCreate()` method will solve this by telling the activity that it would like to make some changes.

To add the overflow menu in another fragment you can repeat the last two steps inside that fragment but change:
    `menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.main_menu_group, false);`

to:
    `menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.main_menu_group, true);`